# Torrent client with per tracker settings

Tags: software-rec, bittorrent

I'm looking for a torrent client with per tracker settings (i.e. ratio, speed limits etc). Windows or Linux, preferably both.

Comment: And what about multi-tracker torrents?

Comment: could you tell us about the underlying motivation of this wish?

Comment: @Bora: Different sites, different rules. SCC, BTN, and all other sites have different rules (found them on Fileshare freak).

Comment: Instead, you can create groups and assign them settings acoordingly.

Comment: Well, I want to maintain good rating at some of the private trackers without too much micromanaging. My uplink is not so great as my downlink so I have to prioritize. Multi-tracker torrents are not an issue: the ones I'm interested in are not multi-tracker.

Comment: Join the crowd. UTorrent users like me have been begging for this for years. http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?pid=30806

Comment: Yeah, I brought it up at the feature request forum last year (or earlier) and got a "duplicate entry" type answer right away. I use utorrent now, but it is not free (as in freedom) and it bothers me more and more.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you may find [rtorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/) (a BitTorrent client for ncurses) useful in your case, something similar was requested ~4 years ago on their [trac](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/ticket/1103).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not already aware of, try [Vuze (formerly Azureus)](http://azureus.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I went through a few of these and [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/) is the best I found so far - it will fit your requirements.

Deluge runs on headless machines and is managed through a console (tty), a web UI and GTK interface. There is a Firefox plugin available to handle .torrent files on a client transparently through the web UI.

I also tried uTorrent on Linux - whilst the Windows implementation is fantastic, the Linux version is not native enough and therefore neither too stable nor too integrated into the system. This may change though over time.

Answer (score 0):

[Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com) is officially Linux and Mac OS only, but otherwise fulfills your requirements.  There is an [unofficial windows port](http://sourceforge.net/projects/trqtw/), which I have never tried.

Transmission is easy to use, I find.   Especially the up/download limits are easy to set, with a simple system of General Limits and per-file limits that override the General Limits.  You can toggle the per-file limits at any time, even remotely.